# Confused about partition function of identical particles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function, identical-particles

The total partition function of N identical, independent particles is $Z^N/N!$ where Z is the partition function of a single particle. To find out the correct magnetization due to N identical atoms of magnetic moment $\mu=-g \mu_B J$, the partition function is taken to be $Z^N$. See page 4 of this note. [http://physics.unl.edu/~cbinek/Paramagnetism%20unit%2022.pptx](http://physics.unl.edu/%7Ecbinek/Paramagnetism%20unit%2022.pptx)    Why is the factor $1/N!$ missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstlly, magnetization  does not care about the $N!$. It's thermodynamic quantities such as specific heat that need the $N!$  Secondly it is not clear whether the powerpoint slides are talking about a paramagnetic gas or a crystal. In the crystal the atoms are, in effect, *distinguishable* because they can be specified by their positions: if they were free to move and exchange places with one another, then we would have to keep the $N!$, As long as they don't move there is no thermodynamic consequence  to  their identity. The crystal  microstates are therefore counted as if the atoms were  distinguishable.